# How can i do this query by pure sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table below

```
 first      second 
-------     ---------- 
100        0 
200        0 
0           400
```

I want to get below result

```
 first      second      result 
-------     ---------- ---------- 
100        0            100 
200        0            300 
0           400         -100
```

As you can see that result parameter is sum of previous (first-sum) How can i write such a query ?

**MYSQL** solution is very simple, but simple solutions are looking for **Microsoft Sql Server.**

```
set @result =0; 
select first, second, @result := @result + first - second as result 
from tablo;
```

results

```
first  second  result   
100    0       100  
200    0       300  
0      400     -100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version with a common table expression.  It also suffers from the lack-of-ordering issue, so I used second, first to get the desired results.

```
WITH cte as
    (
    select [first], [second], [first] - [second] as result,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY second, first) AS sequence
    from tableo
    )

SELECT t.[first], t.[second], SUM(t2.result) AS result
from cte t
JOIN cte t2 on t.sequence >= t2.sequence
GROUP BY t.[first], t.[second]
```

Comment: select * into #gec from tab; alter table #gec add result float; declare @result float; set @result =0; update #gec set @result=result=@result+first-second; select * from #gec;

Answer (score 4):

Your first problem is that you're assuming order where there is none.  A query without an order by clause has no guaranteed order.  Tables without a clustered index don't have a defined order.

So, if we fix that and put an `identity` column on the table so that we do have a well defined order, you can use a recursive CTE do it (in mssql 2005 and newer):

```
with running_sum as (
  select
    t.id, t.first, t.second, t.first-t.second as result
  from
    table t where t.id = 1
  UNION ALL
  select
    t.id, t.first, t.second, r.result+t.first-t.second
  from
    table t
    join running_sum r on r.id = t.id - 1
)
select
  *
from
  running_sum
order by
  id
```